# Landscape LDAP integration

Tags: 16.04, landscape

I am trying to set up a landscape on-premises server for my home lab. I have completed the simple [quickstart installation](https://landscape.canonical.com/set-up-on-prem), and would now like to enable LDAP authentication. I have however not been able to find any documentation on this (..??), and the closest thing I have is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906980/ubuntu-landscape-ldap-authentification) here on askubuntu.com.

The answer in that question gets me there almost. The web interface part of landscape correctly asks me for ldap credentials, but every time I try to register with an existing account, the web interface just spits out

> Unable to validate credentials.

I suppose landscape can't connect to the ldap server, but I have not been able to find any additional information what so ever. The logs in `/etc/log/landscape-server/` does not write any errors, so I am at a loss for how to investigate further.

I have other services and other servers talking just fine with the ldap backend.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it eventually. The linked question incorrectly referenced `/etc/ldap.config`, but should be `/etc/ldap.conf`.

I never found any detail logs, but `pam_ldap` seemed to at least confirm my issue by writing some errors to `/var/log/syslog`.